# Can't get my C program to compile. Makefile error

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a new C program, but I can't get the program to compile. This is because my makefile seems to be wrong. I keep getting "No rule to make target 'all'" and "No rule to make target 'clean'". Here is what I have so far:

Main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

Sleepy() {

main (); {
    printf("Hello world");
}

}
```

Header (Although I haven't done anything to it yet):

```
#ifndef SLEEPY_H_
#define SLEEPY_H_



#endif /* SLEEPY_H_ */
```

And the Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c

Sleepy.o: Sleepy.c Sleepy.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) Sleepy.c

Sleepy: Sleepy.o
$(CC) -o Sleepy.exe Sleepy.o


all: Sleepy

clean:
rm -rf *.0 a.out

make = all
```

I've been reading all kinds of tutorials, but I can't seem to get it to work. Would someone help me with this?

Comment: After the makefile troubles are fixed, you will get complaints from the compiler. Your source is not correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Which is Sleepy.c I assume? Anyway, should I not post questions like this here? 2 down votes seems to say so.

Comment: @blutuu You have some first order issues in `sleepy.c`. First, you need get `main` out of the `Sleepy()` i.e. main function should be defined independently.. Are you trying to write a `CTOR`? Next, main has a `semi-colon` as in `main ();`. For your objective, please *remove* the semi-colon. `main` should return an integer and hence, please define `int main()` and perform a `return 0;` at the end of the main. And finally, in your makefile, you could remove `make = all` at the end of your makefile

Comment: I suppose it's called `Sleepy.c`, it's what you list under "Main program". Ganesh has just spared me the need to list the mistakes there (but you'd better define it as `int main(void)` than just `int main()`). In your makefile, under `clean`, you remove `*.0`, that very probably should be `*.o`. Also, `make = all` shouldn't be in the makefile, and maybe the `all` target must be the first for it to work (not a make expert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your compilation, following changes are required.

**Sleepy.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c

all: Sleepy

Sleepy.o: Sleepy.c Sleepy.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Sleepy.c

Sleepy.exe: Sleepy.o
    $(CC) -o Sleepy.exe Sleepy.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.o Sleepy.exe
```

Please note the change in `clean` rule of your `Makefile`. You will have to remove the executable which is `Sleepy.exe`

**NOTE:** The rules for `Sleepy.o` and `Sleepy` should be offset by a `TAB` and not space. Else, you will run into this error: [`makefile:5: *** missing separator. Stop`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq22_17.html)

Comment: Understood. The 0 was a mistake and I fixed it. Even still with the changes there's no compilation.

Comment: Another thing; Should this be run from the command prompt? Because I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: @blutuu .. please check my latest update. Does this work for you?

Comment: At first it did not work, so what I did was delete the project and remade it. With your makefile configurations I was able to get the program to compile. I think many of these other suggestions would have worked had I done this sooner. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @blutuu... Great.. am happy that you got your project up and running.. Happy programming :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
All: sleepy

sleepy: sleepy.c sleepy.o sleepy.h 
        gcc sleepy.c -o sleepy
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

Comment: `gcc -c sleepy.c -o sleepy.exe` will create an object file and not an executable. One can't run `sleepy.exe` after the compilation step.

Comment: @Ganesh hey thanks. I am unaware of it. I have made changes. Could you tell me then How should make "sleepy.exe" as executable?

Comment: @SRJ .. Even your updated comment is not accurate as `sleepy` will be an object file only. To generate the executable, please use `gcc -o sleepy sleepy.c` i.e. remove `-c` as this tells the compiler to `compile only`

Comment: there is a lot to learn I guess. I haven't thought in too much detail about Makefiles. Thanks one again